# is it possible to search null objects in mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm trying to search null object with python NoneType but got the below error message:

`raise ValidationError(message, errors=errors, field_name=field_name) mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: 'null' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string`

Code for reproducing this issue:

```
class User(mongoengine.Document):
meta = {
    "db_alias": 'core',
    "collection": 'so_users_details'
}
user_name = mongoengine.StringField(required=True)
tag_details = mongoengine.ObjectIdField(null=True)

User(user_name='Sam').save() # This will create a new user with null value in tag_details

User.objects().filter(tag_details=None) # Getting the above error
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to change the default value of `tag_details` to :

```
tag_details = mongoengine.ObjectIdField(blank=True)
```

so you can search for null objects like this:

```
User.objects(Q(tag_details__exists=False))
```